# Questions on embedding

Tags: go, interface, package, embedding

I have trouble constructing the main type of my project: the Descriptor, and its corresponding View (`type View map[string]Descriptor`).

Several sub-algorithms all make use of the View, but they want to add data to the base Descriptors, that is to add methods to the View.

Say I have a base package A and a sub-package B, with the following code:

```
package A

// A.Descriptor only takes care in a Descriptor's address
type Descriptor interface {
    GetAddr() string
}

// Are the names OK?
// I thought of "Describer" for interface name and "Descriptor" for the struct
// But is not that better than Descriptor/BaseDescriptor    
type BaseDescriptor struct {
    Addr string
}
func (d BaseDescriptor) GetAddr() string { return d.Addr }

type View map[string]Descriptor

// A.View implements basic set functionality like Add, Remove, Union...
func (v *View) Add(descs... Descriptor) {
    for _, d := range descs {
        (*v)[d.GetAddr()] = item
    }
}
```

In another package:

```
package B

import (
    "my_project/A"
)

// This package needs an "age" integer associated with each Descriptor
type Descriptor struct {
    gossip.BaseDescriptor

    age int
}

// Now, I want a new version of View with the ability to increment
// its Descriptors' age
func (v *NewView) IncrementAge() {
    for key, val := range *v {
        // If NewView directly handles B.Descriptor *struct*:
        (*v)[key].age += 1
        // Else, I could implement a
        // "func (d Descriptor) IncrementAge() Descriptor" to do so:
        (*v)[key] = val.IncrementAge()
    }
}

// But how should I define NewView?
```

I have been banging my head on the wall listening to Rob Pike tell me how simpler interfaces are much better than big ones. But now that I tackle Descriptor, that used to be a bigger "all-in-one" interface, I really can't figure out how to split it well. So any advice is welcome!

Basically, my goal is to be able to pass the same Descriptor struct around my different sub-algorithms, the final Descriptor being an embedding of A.Descriptor, B.Descriptor etc. Each embedding adding a bit of functionality.

Comment: If all of your `Descriptor`s have different functionality, and i don't mean one method implemented differently, but different methods altogether, then i think using an interface makes no sense and you should just use your `struct` type with its embedded members.

Comment: I would, if I could! Two points make me think I am stuck with this interface/struct pair. 1: If X is embedded in Y, I believe I can't provide a type Y to a `func f(x X)` ; 2: I can't do type conversions like `y.(X)`, which I use in View's `IncrementAge` below. In other words, I can't store more than X in my original `type View map[string]X`.

Comment: How about embedding Y in X and passing X to all your `func`'s that need to handle X and Y? then you can access increment age of y by `x.Y.IncrementAge()`

Comment: In this case you revert the dependency tree. (But really, thanks for trying! I'm too OO for Go, it drives me crazy!) The whole point of my problem is to have package A offering minimal standalone View functionality, with by B (and C and D...) making their own additions independently, while allowing to pass around the same data structure (the View).